# Minimal number of edit operations to convert string to match regular expression

Tags: regex, levenshtein-distance

Is there a way to calculate minimal number of operations (insertions, deletions, substitutions) in order to convert some string to match some regular expression?

For example, minimal number of operations to convert string `baba` to match regex `(ab)+` is 2: it needs to be turned either into `ababab` (+2 characters) or `ab` (-2 characters).

Comment: What would be the Levenstein difference between aaaaaaaa  and the regex a{0,100} ?

Comment: I suppose it would be 0.

Comment: @DhruvPathak Granted it's not a good indicator *by itself*. But comparing the Levenshtein distance of two string to the regex they match could be interseting.

Comment: @Curious More like `7` actually - you need to replace 7 characters in `aaaaaaaa` to get `a{0,100}`. The Leveinshtein distance is not related to regexes: it measures the distance between two raw strings.

Comment: @Rightleg I think that regex _a{0,100}_ means that letter a occurs up to a hundred times in a string. Since string _aaaaaaaa_ completely matches this regular expression it's Levenshtein distance would be 0.

Comment: @Curious But unfortunately, that's not what Levenshtein distance acutally measures. It only compares the similarity of **two raw strings**.

Comment: In fact, I want to calculate the minimum number of operations needed to convert a string to match particular regular expression.

Comment: @Rightleg Yes, I know that. But, I want to know is this task possible to solve and how. I may have clumsily titled the question.

Comment: Please let me know if you manage to achieve anything with the vague idea I proposed. I'd be glad to see if one can make something out of it.

Answer (score 4):

You could compute the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between a string and a regular expression, but it wouldn't make much sense, because this measures the similarity of two raw strings.

What you want is probably to measure the number of operations that the string would need to undergo in order to match the pattern.

Here is a solution, based on the graph theory.

First, we'll need to build the automaton that represents the language defined by the regular expression.
[Thompson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction_algorithm) will help you here.

Once we've constructed this automaton, we can try our best to make the expression match, and modify it whenever it's going off.
The number of modifications will be the distance from the string to the language described by the regex.

Here is an example, for a basic regex: `.*a.*`.
The corresponding automaton is:

[image]

Let's check the distance of the `bbb` string.

1. The first character is `b`, so we stay in `1`
2. `b` again, so we stay in `1`
3. Still `b`, we stay in 1
4. The string is empty, and we're still not in the final state `2`.
   So let's add an `a`. Now, we can go to `2`.
5. We're in `2`, and no character is left in the string, so we're good.

We made one modification to the original string, so the distance from `bbb` to the `.*a.*` regex is `1`.
In fact, the distance of any word to that language is either `0` or `1`, because it is equivalent to that word containing an `a`, which is binary.

This is only an idea, and it might have flaws, but I think that you can do something with that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to make this work for me.